# Getting error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token

Tags: c++

I'm not sure what's wrong. I'm pretty new to c++, but I don't see any problems. I've read through a bunch of other stack overflow pages, but none of them seem to address my issue.

This is from terminal

```
Joshs-MacBook-Pro:desktop Josh$ g++ BinaryCompare.cpp
BinaryCompare.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
BinaryCompare.cpp:9: error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token
```

Here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isGreater(string a, string b);

int main (){
    if(greater("11", "00"))
        cout << "hello"<<endl;
  return 0;
}

bool isGreater(string a, string b){
    if(a.length() > b.length() ) return false;
    if(a.length() < b.length() ) return true;

    for(int i= 0; i < a.length(); i++){
        if(a[i] != b[i]){
            if(a[i] == '1') return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: Did you, by any chance, mean to call `isGreater` rather than `greater` in `main`?

Comment: And is really `000001` greater than `111`?

Comment: @Mats Ahhhh I feel so dumb. Thank you for pointing that out, it compiles. I'm guaranteed no leading zeros

Comment: There is definitely leading zeros in your `"00"` example you have right now (well, ok, pedantically, one leading zero).

Comment: I suppose. That's more of a test though.

Comment: Is there a simple way to remove leading zeros, or would I need a while loop?

Comment: If you want a compare between `0000001` and `111` to work, you should probably ADD zeros until the two strings are equal length, rather than remove zeros. But if the strings are guaranteed to be equal length, or not have surplus leading zeros, you don't need to do anything. You should then warn about `if (a.length() > 1 && a[0] == '0') cout << "Warning, unexpected leading zeros" << endl;` and same for `b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good example why `using namespace std` is not always a good idea.

You've typo'd

```
if(greater("11", "00"))
```

which should really be

```
if(isGreater("11", "00"))
```

...and manage to hit the name of [a class template defined in the `std` namespace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/greater/) you've just imported whole-sale. Thereby the confusing error message.

Answer (score 2):

`greater()` should be replaced with `isGreater()` on line 9 within if.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from fixing the `greater` call to make a call to  `isGreater` on line 9, you probably want to make sure that you pad the string with zero's until both strings are the same length, instead of just returning `true` or `false` in the first couple of lines in `isGreater`.

Comment: should add side note: about *`And is really 000001 greater than 111`*